# Check instance of struct member already created

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I'm currently stuck at a very specific problem. I have a `map` of structs like:

```
std::map<int, MyStruct> myMap;

typedef struct
{
    long a;
    int b;
    MyObject* object;
} MyStruct;
```

On the structs creation `object` is always set to `nullptr`:

```
void createNewStruct(int id)
{
    MyStruct newStruct{2L, 1, nullptr}; // create with no object
    myMap.insert(std::pair(id, newStruct)); // store in map
}
```

I do this because I may have thousands of structs in the `map`, but only a few may need an actual "object" which itself is pretty large.

The `object` itself has a limited lifetime, and it should *show* if it's currently not shown, and not show if it's currently showing. If the end of the objects lifetime is reached it calls stopped(this):

```
void doShow(int id)
{
    if(myMap[id].object == nullptr)
    {
        MyObject* newObject = new MyObject();
        connect(object, SIGNAL(stopped(MyObject*), this, (objectStopped(MyObject*)); // create callback to delete object later

        myMap[id].object = newObject;
        // do something with object
    }
}
```

Now if stopped(this) is called I try to clean up:

```
void objectStopped(MyObject* object)
{
    // do something with object

    delete object;
    object = nullptr; //????
}
```

But obviously this is not working as intended because the check to `nullptr` won't ever be true again.

**So what i want to achieve is:** I have a `map` with a lot of structs, but only few of these structs need the `object`. How can I create and delete this object correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a C++11 compiler (which you should), you can make use of the `id`:

```
connect(object, 
        SIGNAL(stopped(MyObject*), 
        this, 
        []() { delete myMap[id]; myMap[id] = nullptr; });
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I was mentally stuck at:

        `Object* a = 0x02;
        Object* b = a;

        a = nullptr;
        b = 0x02;  // still points`

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this, is giving to `MyStruct` the *ownership* of `MyObject`, and not using external functions to manage that allocation.
If you do that, your design in general will improve.

For example you can give to `MyStruct` some functions to manage the creation of the `MyObject` structure: `createObject()` to create one, or `destroyObject()` to destroy it, a function to check if the object is present, and you can give to `MyStruct` his own `doShow()` member function, so your external `doShow(int id)` function will get the correct `MyStruct` for that specific 'id' and then will call `MyStruct::doShow()` nothing more.
When you destroy a `MyStruct` object, it will also deallocate its `MyObject`, if any, automatically, without worrying about it will callbacks, signal/slots mechanisms etc.

So, bottom line: I'd just make `MyStruct` object smarter, and giving to it the complete *ownership* of the `MyObject` class. I'm sure this will improve the overall design.

Comment: My opinion is that you should use `std::unique_ptr` in the struct for simplicity, and instead of trying to `delete` the object in a member function of that object (which is confusing) just make sure that who calls the "stopped" function resets the pointer afterwards.